Proving that a function is one-to-one (injective)
The question is to show that the function $ f(x) =  2x + |\cos x|$ is both one-one and onto. I have managed to show that it is onto but got stuck at proving that it is also one-to-one.
To prove this I thought of using the first derivative and showing that the function is always increasing. For both cases of the absolute value, the derivative is $f'(x) = 2 - \sin x$ or $f'(x)=2+ \sin x$ which are both strictly greater than zero for all real values of x. However, at the points where $\cos x$ changes sign, the function is not differentiable. My question is, how can I show that the function is increasing at these points as well? Is there some calculus-based method for these points as well?

Hint: If a function is strictly increasing on $[a, b]$ and on $[b, c]$ then it is strictly increasing on $[a, c]$.

Here, "increasing" is understood as strictly increasing.
If $f$ is increasing on $(a,b)$ and on $(b,c)$ and continuous at $b$, then $f$ is increasing on $(a,c)$.
More details:

If $f$ is increasing on $(a,b)$ and left continuous at $b$, then $f$ is increasing on $(a,b]$, since
$$\forall x\in(a,b)\quad f(x)<f\left(\frac{x+b}2\right)\le\lim_{b^-}f=f(b).$$
Similarly, if $f$ is increasing on $(b,c)$ and right continuous at $b$, then $f$ is increasing on $[b,c)$.
If $f$ is increasing on $(a,b]$ and on $[b,c)$, then it increasing on $(a,c)$.


No need to use drivatives of $f$. Suppose $2x+|\cos x|=2y+|\cos y|$ and (w.l.o.g.)  $x\ge y$. Then, by Mean Vaue Theorem, $2x-2y=|\cos x|-|\cos y|\le |\cos x -\cos y|=|x-y| |-\sin t|$ for some $t$ between $x$ and $y$. This gives $2x-2y\leq |x-y|$ so $x=y$.

Suppose $x \neq y$ also suppose w.l.o.g $x>y$ ,and to get a contradiction suppose

$2x+ |cos(x)|$   = $2y+ |cos(y)|$

Since $x \neq y$. We can construct the inequality

$2 = \dfrac{|cos(y)| - |cos(x)|}{x-y} \leq \dfrac{|cos(x) - cos(y)|}{x-y} = \bigg |\dfrac{cos(x) - cos(y)}{x-y}\bigg |$

Then use the mean value theorem. Vola !
